# Custom GUI for Credential Provider

Tags: c++, .net, authentication, credential-providers

I've designed a facial recognition algorithm around OpenCV/EmguCV (hasn't been beaten yet!)

Now, I obviously want to use it to login my computer. The best way to do this, it seems, is to implement a custom credential provider (like the picture lock one supplied with windows 8). But as far as I can tell, credential providers cannot define a custom GUI(which mine would need), having to make do with defining fields to LoginUI to render their UI.

But I have seen credential providers with custom UIs(picture lock, commercial bio-metric ones etc.). Am I missing something? Is there some undocumented way of doing this? Or am I really just clueless about credential providers?

I'm a .NET programmer by default, but I don't mind converting my algo to C++(shouldn't be hard, since it is OpenCV)

Comment: hm... As far as I remember credential providers are loaded by LogonUI.exe which has system rights, so as a solution, maybe it's possible to make a call to GetDC(0) inside provider and get handle, then do everything you want.

Comment: So that should get a handle to LoginUI's window? Does that mean I can make changes to it, or am I supposed to parent a UI window to it to display(I've heard of people doing that before, the only problem is I kind of want to make the custom UI blend in with the login screen). Any idea on exactly how to modify the Login screen?

Comment: Any solution for that???

Answer (score 0):

If you make a credential provider, you can define a custom UI in the common.h file.

This ui will be limited and a pain in the ass, but this is the only way i know. You can do additionnal initialization in the Initialize() method of the class that implement ICredentialProviderCredential2;

You can update a field later like that :

```
hr = _pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldString(this, SFI_LARGE_TEXT, L"New text");
```

You can also pop window like that :

```
HWND hwndOwner = NULL;
_pCredProvCredentialEvents->OnCreatingWindow(&hwndOwner);
::MessageBox(hwndOwner, L"The text of the new window", L"new window title", MB_ICONWARNING);
```

If you want a good starting point tis repo is very usefull :
https://github.com/DavidWeiss2/windows-Credential-Provider-library